# How to scrape the entire Web with Scrapy (all domains are allowed) on a domain per domain basis?

Tags: scrapy

I am new to Scrapy framework and I would like to create a spider (or multiple spiders if this is preferable) that would scrape the entire Web on a domain per domain basis. In other words, I would like the spider to process all the pages under a specific domain looking for specific keywords in each page, then output word counts for each keyword for that domain, and then move to the next domain.

According to the [documentation on the official website](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#), Scrapy crawls in depth-first order:

> By default, Scrapy uses a LIFO queue for storing pending requests, which basically means that it crawls in DFO order. This order is more convenient in most cases.

Is it easy to implement a domain per domain crawl with the Scrapy framework? What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: ALL the web? Hope you got a big hard drive! 

Comment: There is no reliable way to crawl all pages of any given domain. If you _need_ that, you have a problem.

Comment: I do not need (and do not intend) to scrape all the web, I just need the search to not be limited to a fixed series of domains and, most importantly, I need to crawl the web on a domain per domain basis. What is the best way to achieve that with Scrapy? I can implement a simple crawler with the python threading library, but there are many other things to take into account for a reliable crawler (such as dealing with robots.txt files).